# Ubuntu 17.10 / Gnome 3: Hide users from login screen

Tags: gnome, login

I have a few users in my system which I only use for specific applications, but I never want to log in as these users from the login screen. I would like to keep the users, but remove them from the list. Alternatively, setting myself as the default login user would also work. How do I achieve this?

I've tried creating a file for the user in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/EWF` (EWF is the user I want to hide) with the following contents:

```
[User]  
Language=   
XSession=gnome  
SystemAccount=true
```

But the file just gets deleted after I restart, and the user still appears in the login list.

I've also tried adding the following section in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

```
[Greeter]
Exclude=user1,user2,nobody
```

but that didn't help either.

Comment: "EWF" may not be the correct username. Log in as EWF and open Terminal. Then run `whoami`. It should show the correct username for EWF.

Comment: @pomsky that was it. Although the user appeared as EWF on the login screen, the actual user name was `ewf` (as shown in `/etc/passwd` and in `/home/`). Thanks!